# How can you write a class that sums the cells of a matrix around a specified cell location?

Tags: java, matrix

Just to preface this, I'm brand new to Java. I'm confused how I should go about this task, but I gave it a shot. I'm not sure what I should be returning in this case, as the variable "result" is non-static, so I can't return that in this context (it also contains an array which is another issue). Below is the code I've written.

```
class Main {
    // create a variable to hold the array
    // initialize the array with the values shown
    private static int[][] mat = new int[5][5];
    {
        int[][] mat = { { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, { 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 }, { 6, 7, 1, 2, 5 }, { 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 }, { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 } };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("The sum of 1, 1 is " + sumAround(1, 1));
    }

    public static int sumAround(int row, int col) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mat[i].length; j++) {
                int result = 0;
                result += mat[Math.max(0, i - 1)][j];

                if (i == mat.length - 1) {
                    result += mat[i][j];
                }

                else {
                    result += mat[i + 1][j];
                }

                result += mat[i][Math.max(0, j - 1)];
                if (j == mat[0].length - 1) {
                    result += mat[i][j];
                }

                else {
                    result += mat[i][j + 1];
                }

                mat[i][j] = result;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                System.out.println(mat[i][j]);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I got the question wrong but why can't you return result? Shouldn't be a problem?

Comment: make your question clear. Around the cell - does it mean eight (maximum, in some cases there will be less) surrounded cells? In that case the sumAround function will be a simple addition statement that sums up all eight (subject to existence) cells around that specific cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understood, you are looking for the summation of cells around a specific cell. Say the specific cell is (row, col) then there will be maximum eight cells around it depends on the position. Remember Java array location are zero based.

[image]

Here is the solution, **I just focused on sumAround method**, you can improve your Main class so that it will work for any size matrix. **The code is tested and works fine.**

```
class Main
{
   // create a variable to hold the array
   // initialize the array with the values shown

   static int[][] mat =
         { { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, { 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 }, { 6, 7, 1, 2, 5 }, { 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 }, { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 } };

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      System.out.println("The sum of 1, 1 is " + sumAround(2, 3, 5, 5));
   }


   public static int sumAround(int row, int col, int max_row, int max_col)
   {

      int dx[] = { -1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 };
      int dy[] = { -1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1 };

      int sum = 0;

      for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
      {
         if (row + dx[i] >= 0 && row + dx[i] < max_row && col + dy[i] >= 0 && col + dy[i] < max_col)
            sum += mat[row + dx[i]][col + dy[i]];

      }

      return sum;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying - should have made the question clearer. I wanted to include the value of the initial position (e.g. 1,1 = 7) in the sum, but I was able to do that by adding `sum += mat[row][col];` after the initialization of the variable `sum`.

Comment: In that case just initialize the sum with this, int sum = mat[row][col]; And if the solution answers your question then accept it as an answer please.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than iterating over the entire array, you can use a quick little bit of math to directly reference the adjacent indicies. For the purposes of how I would think of a grid of 3 numbers, let's give them a single index:

[image]

Now, for the more spatially orientated, we can actually convert this index into a row/column pair; Dividing by the length (3) gives us the current row, and the remainder from dividing the length (3) will be the column:

[image]

Finally, if you subtract the origin / "minus one", you'll get the distances from the origin point to the current index:

[image]

The end result is a pretty quick iteration, and even has a trick to allow summing the corners/center or not:

```
public static int sumAround(int row, int column, boolean center, boolean corners) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        //4 == center 
        if (i == 4 || !center) { continue; }
        //i&1==0 is an even number (corner or center, center already handled)
        else if (i & 1 == 0 && !corners) { continue; }
        int rOffset = (i / 3) - 1;
        int cOffset = (i % 3) - 1;
        result += mat[row + rOffset][column + cOffset];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: "Rather than iterating over the entire array" - this line isn't clear. No one is iterating over the entire array to solve this problem, just eight entries around the cell. However I am interested to understand your technique. Can you give an example call of the sumAround method with the values of its parameters. Thanks.

Comment: @ManojBanik the OP himself was doing so, see his original for loop. An example call for my above method would be like `sumAround(3, 4, true, true)` to sum a 3x3 grid centered on 3,4, or `(3, 4, true, false)` for a plus sign, etc. In a very two-dimensional way, this can be thought of as a vector math question. I provided the booleans since I wasn't sure what the OP wanted to include at the time; he can see how it's done himself above

Comment: In comparison to your solution, it saves you that need for a `dx`/`dy` array

Answer (score -1):

The reason that you can't return is you declared it inside the inner loop(loop for j) and it has just scope for that loop, not for the function. Simply declare the result(int result = 0;) at first line of the function before the loop and then you will be able to return it.